# how to set the height of a listview when the activity is initialized

Tags: android, listview

my purpose is to set the height of a listView when the activity is initialized.
the height of my listview is less than the screen, and after intialized I want to get the height of the listView and make the height plus an integer,then set the listvView's height with the new number.

But when I use  `listview.getMeasuredHeight()` or `listview.getLayoutParams().height` in `onCreate` or `onStart` or `onResume`.The answer is always zero.
How can I get the right answer?

I am new to android, thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548345/android-how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-the-list-view-dynamically

Comment: Why don't you just add a padding to your list view ?

Comment: thaks for Samir.This is useful：http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548345/android-how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-the-list-view-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

That seems weird. Anyway, you can place your ListView in a ViewGroup lik LinearLayour, RelativeLayout and set the listview height to fill_parent. And then set the height of the viewgroup outside.

Comment: I just want to set the height dynamically.Anyway thank you for your answer.