# IllegalStateException map size should not be 0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a `MapFragment` that displays a map

if the user goes away from the activity (or the device goes to sleep) with the map then comes back `onResume` gets called and I move the map back to a marker.

however when I move the camera I get an exception

```
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ecm2.android/ecm2.android.EMGNoteMapActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map size should not be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
 07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map size should not be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at maps.as.i.b(Unknown Source)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at maps.ah.w.a(Unknown Source)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at maps.ah.s.a(Unknown Source)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at maps.ah.an.b(Unknown Source)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at bgc.onTransact(SourceFile:92)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.animateCamera(Unknown Source)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(Unknown Source)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at ecm2.android.Fragments.EMGMap.centerOnNote(EMGMap.java:340)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at ecm2.android.Fragments.EMGMap.fetchMapSettings(EMGMap.java:283)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at ecm2.android.Fragments.EMGMap.onResume(EMGMap.java:289)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1820)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:412)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5195)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
07-23 16:28:42.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19095):    ... 12 more
```

This is my camera movement on my `onResume`

```
if(map != null && northEast != null && southWest != null){
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast),10));
    }else if(map != null && centerPoint != null){
        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
         .target(centerPoint).zoom(17).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
    }
```

If I take out the camera movement it does not crash but does not go back to the point of they moved away from it or something.

I check to make sure the `map` is not null so I do not know what is causing the error?

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13692908/937715

Comment: As previous answer suggested, I proposed [this one][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825157/1755300

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Map size should not be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.
```

This should be clear enough. You cannot call

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast),10));
```

before the layout is complete. You need to use 3 param version instead.

See the documentation here: [`newLatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngBounds%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int%29)

Aternatively you may listen for the layout to complete instead of calling this code in `onResume`.

Comment: how can I listen when the layout is complete though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795862/i-want-to-measure-the-height-of-the-listview-gethight-0/11796244#11796244

Comment: Use OnMapReadyCallback to know when map is loaded.